# How to not split an umlaut?

Tags: python, iso, python-re

I want to use the following function to get words out of a text and put them into a list:

```
list = re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  'text hier einfügen').split()
```

Output of list is:

> ['text', 'hier', 'einfügen']

This works fine. But as soon as I add to my code the iso:

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
```

...it doesn't work anymore. The ouput becomes:

> ['text', 'hier', 'einf', 'gen']

How can I avoid that? I need this iso coding because in HTML it wouldn't print the German text correctly otherwise.

Additional information (more details):

I have a form like this:

```
<form action="text_ch.py" method="post" name="search"><textarea cols="50" name="comment" rows="10">Text hier einfügen...</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Analyse"><p></p>
</form>
```

And the python file is then:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-

import cgi
import re

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
user_text =  form.getvalue('comment')
user_text_output = user_text
wordList = re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  user_text).split()
wordList = [x.lower() for x in wordList]

# HTML Ausgabe

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print '<html>'
print '<head>'
print '<title>Title</title>'
print '<meta charset=\"utf-8\"/>'
print '</head>'
print '<body>'
print '<div style=\"width: 40%; margin: auto; border: 1px solid #333;box-shadow: 8px 8px 5px #444;padding: 8px 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:medium; line-height:1.5;\">'

print wordList
print "</div>"
print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

And the output in HMTL is:

> ['text', 'hier', 'einf', 'gen']

Comment: The "coding cookie" only affects the characters that you can use in string literals in your source.  I doesn't affect how html is rendered, unless you are storing the html in python source files.  Can you provide a [mre] that demonstrates the html issue?

Comment: When you say "add to my code the iso," do you mean you actually used `str.encode('latin_1')` or something else?

Comment: I do store the html in python source files. And the issue I have is not HTML as it works fine now, but why doesn't the 're' work as soon as I delete this coding line?

Comment: If your file is still saved as UTF-8, then the comment tells your parser to treat the UTF-8 pair `\xc3\xbc` as two different ISO-8859 characters. This will affect the regular expression match.

Comment: If your html doesn't specify a character encoding (in a `<meta>` tag) or if the webserver doesn't add a `Content-Type` header to requests then a user agent may fall back to using `ISO-8859-1` as the default encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `[^\w]` ("any non-word character"), just use `[\s]` ("any whitespace character").

Also, use the method `re.split()` instead of `re.sub().split()`. It's just more straightforward that way.

```
import re

lst = re.split("[\s]",  'text hier einfügen')
['text', 'hier', 'einfügen']
```

If you're worried about catching command characters like `<`, `>`, `/`, etc., then it's probably easiest to just manually list them inside the regex - there's only a finite amount inside ASCII that are valid HTML control characters, anyway.

Comment: Again it doesn't work with the coding cookie: I tried it in Visual Studio Code and the output is like yours but as soon as I add the cookie; # -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*- the output is now ['text', 'hier', 'einfÃ¼gen']

Comment: You can't just add a coding cookie. You have to also change how the file is stored. How you do this will depend on your code environment. It looks like the file is being stored as UTF-8, but you told Python it's encoded using ISO-8859-1.

Comment: I also tried telling Python in this coding cookie to use  # -- coding: utf-8 --  and the result is then that it saves the umlaute in code like \xc3\xbc2.